# Unity c# change light temperatur with script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im trying to write a script that makes the temperature of the light whatever number is set in the float

i need this for later reference when i add a slider or selectable options that determine the temperature of the light

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
public class lightchange : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public float Temp = 2000f;
  
    private void pp()
    {
        Light lightcomp = GetComponent<Light>();

        lightcomp.colorTemperature = Temp;
    }


}
```

this is my code but it doesnt seem to work and this is all i could find online to edit components[what im trying to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1tuF.png)

Comment: Do you actually call `pp()` from anywhere?

Comment: as mentioned already if you do not actively call this method from somewhere of course it is never executed ...